# Insert json into postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to insert a json object , supplied by the ARC client (similar to postman) into my webService controller, then into a PostgreSQL 11.4 dB, using Java 8, Eclipse and SpringBoot. I'm getting the following error:

```
2019-07-10 13:02:42.356 ERROR 21516 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO cwb_patent(patent_number,created_date,patent_data) VALUES (?,current_timestamp,cast(? AS JSON)) ON CONFLICT (patent_number) DO UPDATE SET patent_data  = cast(? AS JSON), created_date = current_timestamp]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.clarivate.singularity.chemworkbench.webservices.common.PatentChemicalData. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.clarivate.singularity.chemworkbench.webservices.common.PatentChemicalData. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:967) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
```

My query is:

```
public static final String mergeCwbPatent = "INSERT INTO cwb_patent" + 
        "(patent_number,created_date,patent_data)" +
        " VALUES (:patent_number,current_timestamp,cast(:patent_data AS JSON))" +
        " ON CONFLICT (patent_number)" +
        " DO UPDATE SET patent_data  = cast(:patent_data AS JSON), created_date = current_timestamp";
```

My controller is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/merge-patent-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Long  mergePatentChemicalData(@RequestBody  PatentChemicalData patentChemicalData) { 
    Long ret = db.mergeCwbPatent(patentChemicalData);
    return ret;
}
```

And the method doing the insert is:

```
public Long mergeCwbPatent(PatentChemicalData pcd)
{
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Long ret = null;
    String patentNumber;

    if (pcd == null )
    {
        logger.error("DS4A Trying to Insert invalid PatentChemicalData into CWB_PATENT");
    }else {
        patentNumber=pcd.getPatentChemicalData().getPatentNumber();

        logger.debug("DS4B Inserting data for patentNumber = " + patentNumber + " into cwb_patent");
        parameters.put("patent_number", patentNumber);  // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
        parameters.put("patent_data", pcd);   // This is the JSON object

        ret = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SqlQueries.mergeCwbPatent, parameters,Long.class);

    }

    return ret;
}
```

The stacktrace says "Use Use setObject()" but that not applicable to my parameters HashMap. 
This [tenmilessquare](https://tenmilesquare.com/working-with-spring-jdbc-template-and-postgres-json/) link suggests i'm on the right track but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to convert your JSON object to a String e.g. using Jackson

Comment: You seem to be trying to write a POJO to your database, expecting it to convert it to JSON automatically. I don't believe it works that way. You have to convert the POJO to JSON, then save it into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @a_horse_with_no_name advice I added a function to convert the PatentChemicalData object to a string:

```
public String patentChemicalDataToJson(PatentChemicalData pcd) throws JsonProcessingException {
     ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();
     String jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(pcd);
     return jsonStr;
}
```

Then in mergeCwbPatent() I used this function as suggested:

```
String jsonPcdStr= sf.patentChemicalDataToJson(pcd);
parameters.put("patent_data", jsonPcdStr);
```

And it worked fine.
I already had Jackson included and I thought that SpringBoot did the Jackson conversion Automatically, but it doesn't. The problem with SpringBoot is that it makes you lazy!